# How to compress serveral, large, high entropy, but very similar files?

Tags: linux, backup, compression, archiving

I have several big (as in: bigger than any dictionary, 100s of GBs) files. These files are very high entropy and compress very poorly. However these files are (as far as i can tell) almost completely identical. (And not actually compressed)

As a testcase tried a small scale simulation:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=random count=1G

cat random random random > 3random

gz -1 < 3random > 3random.gz
xz -1 < 3random > 3random.xz
```

I think this simulates packing a tar with my files quite well. I'm not surprised it turns out that neither gz nor xz can compress these files, in fact they get slightly larger.

Is there a sensible way to compress these files? This is for (offline-) archive proposes only, decompressing won't be done frequently.

Comment: I mean the compression ratio was slightly above 1, so it didn't compress, as expected of random data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with a file of 10MB of pseudo-random data and make two copies of it:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=f1 bs=1M count=10
$ cp f1 f2
$ cp f1 f3
```

Let's alter those copies so that they are "almost completely identical" (as you said):

```
$   # Avoid typos and improve readability
$ alias random='od -t u4 -N 4 /dev/urandom |
  sed -n "1{s/^\S*\s//;s/\s/${fill}/g;p}"'
$ alias randomize='dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 seek="$(
    echo "scale=0;$(random)$(random)$(random)$(random) % (1024*1024*10)" | bc -l
  )" count="$( echo "scale=0;$(random)$(random) % 512 + 1" |
    bc -l )" conv=notrunc'
$   # In files "f2" and "f3, replace 1 to 512Bytes of data with other
$   #+ pseudo-random data in a pseudo-random position. Do this 3
$   #+ times for each file
$ randomize of=f2
$ randomize of=f2
$ randomize of=f2
$ randomize of=f3
$ randomize of=f3
$ randomize of=f3
```

Now we can compress the data in each file to see what happens:

```
$ xz -1 < f1 > f1.xz
$ xz -1 < f2 > f2.xz
$ xz -1 < f3 > f3.xz
$ ls -lh f{1..3}{,.xz}
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 10M may 29 09:31 f1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 11M may 29 10:07 f1.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 10M may 29 10:00 f2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 11M may 29 10:07 f2.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 10M may 29 10:05 f3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 11M may 29 10:07 f3.xz
```

We can see that this actually increases the size of the data. Now lets transform the data into hex human-readable data (well, sort of) and compress the result:

```
$ xxd f1 | tee f1.hex | xz -1 > f1.hex.xz
$ xxd f2 | tee f2.hex | xz -1 > f2.hex.xz
$ xxd f3 | tee f3.hex | xz -1 > f3.hex.xz
$ ls -lh f{1..3}.hex*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 42M may 29 10:03 f1.hex
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 22M may 29 10:04 f1.hex.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 42M may 29 10:04 f2.hex
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 22M may 29 10:07 f2.hex.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 42M may 29 10:05 f3.hex
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 22M may 29 10:07 f3.hex.xz
```

Data went really big. Four times in hex, twice if hex is compressed. Now the fun part: let's compute the difference between the hex and compress that:

```
$ diff f{1,2}.hex | tee f1-f2.diff | xz -1 > f1-f2.diff.xz
$ diff f{1,3}.hex | tee f1-f3.diff | xz -1 > f1-f3.diff.xz
$ ls -lh f1-*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 7,8K may 29 10:04 f1-f2.diff
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 4,3K may 29 10:06 f1-f2.diff.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 2,6K may 29 10:06 f1-f3.diff
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 1,7K may 29 10:06 f1-f3.diff.xz
```

And that's lovely. Let's summarize:

```
$   # All you need to save to disk is this
$ du -cb f1{,-*z}
10485760        f1
4400    f1-f2.diff.xz
1652    f1-f3.diff.xz
10491812        total
$   # This is what you would have had to store
$ du -cb f{1..3}
10485760        f1
10485760        f2
10485760        f3
31457280        total
$   # Compared to "f2"'s original size, this is the percentage
$   #+ of all the new information you need to store about it
$ echo 'scale=4; 4400 * 100 / 31457280' | bc -l
.0419
$   # Compared to "f3"'s original size, this is the percentage
$   #+ of all the new information you need to store about it
$ echo 'scale=4; 1652 * 100 / 10485760' | bc -l
.0157
$   # So, compared to the grand total, this is the percetage
$   #+ of information you need to store 
$ echo 'scale=2; 10491812 * 100 / 10485760' | bc -l
33.35
```

The more files you have, the better this works.
To make a restoration test of the data from your compressed diffs of "f2":

```
$ xz -d < f1-f2.diff.xz > f1-f2.diff.restored
$   # Assuming you haven't deleted "f1.diff":
$ patch -o f2.hex.restored f1.hex f1-f2.diff.restored
patching file f1.hex
$ diff f2.hex.restored f2.hex # No diffs will be found unless corrupted
$ xxd -r f2.hex.restored f2.restored # We get the completely restored file
$ diff -q f2 f2.restored # No diffs will be found unless corrupted
```

**REMARKS**

- You don't need some of the files generated here, like the compressed versions of the original files and the compressed hex. I made those just to make a point.
- The success of this method greatly depends on the meaning of "almost completely identical". You need to make tests. I made some tests and this works great for many, many types of data (namely, database dumps and even edited images and videos). I actually use this for some backups.
- A more sophisticated method is using librsync, but this works greatly in many situations and will work perfectly on almost any *nix environment without the need of installing new software.
- On the down side, this might require some scripting.
- I don't know any tool that does all this.

Comment: That's very hackish... but great.

Answer (score 1):

gzip works on 32Kb blocks so would help just if the same patterns are in a 32Kb range (which is not your case). For xz you could try passing a very large **--block-size** but you need a lot of spare memory (see the **--memlimit** options).

Comment: I don't think that works, the size of the files are beyond any reasonable block size.

Comment: `xz --block-size` refers to chunks of compressed data.  It's useful for random access since you need only start at the beginning of a block rather than reading the entire archive.  The XZ _DictSize_ is what you're thinking of, and that's dictated by the preset.  Try `xz -9` for the largest dictionray size (64MB).